# piwik capture value behind dynamically generated download button from asp

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, matomo

A web site is developped in asp.net and let people choose pictures to download.
The website groups them togheter and people can then push a download button per picture.

As we never know how many pictures that eventually will be downloaded the button are dynamically generated.

I'm  not permitted to alter the asp.net code on the server only in the piwik part...

The problem is that also the id's are dynamically generated..
I have tried with this:

```
    $("h2").on("click", "a.button button-dl", function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

But got no result, In this case I would like to retrieve "276173" in a variable.
I hope that somebody can help me, thanks for reading
Guy

```
<table class="checkout-basket" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Asset</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="width:30px;">
                                    <input id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_CbFlag" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphContent$gvBasketitem$ctl02$CbFlag" />
                                </td><td style="width:80px;">
                                    <a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Bent u zeker dat u deze asset wil verwijderen?&#39;);" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_lbDelete" class="button" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphContent$gvBasketitem$ctl02$lbDelete&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">verwijder</a>
                                </td><td style="width:100px;">
                                                <img id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_Image1" src="../../cache/images/thumb/3AF267A169AAED70770F0EEE7E74FBB61A526EBB_156.jpg" style="width:80px;border-width:0px;" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <h2>
                                                        <a href='/nl-BE/asset/276173/'>
                                                            276173
                                                        </a>
                                                    </h2>
                                                  <h2>
                                                        <a href='/nl-BE/asset/276173/'>
                                                            20151109_113939_0040
                                                        </a>
                                                    </h2>

                                                <a class="button button-dl" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphContent$gvBasketitem$ctl02$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="margin-top: 4px;"><img style="position: relative; top: 4px; right: 5px" src="/images/picto/download.png" />Download</a>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_pnl">

                                        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphContent$gvBasketitem$ctl02$hfAsset" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_hfAsset" value="276173" />
                                        <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_rblPrint" class="rbl"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_rblPrint_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphContent$gvBasketitem$ctl02$rblPrint" value="False" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_rblPrint_0">Download</label><br /><input id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_rblPrint_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphContent$gvBasketitem$ctl02$rblPrint" value="True" /><label for="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_rblPrint_1">Print</label></span>
                                        <div class="printFormat" style="display: none; padding: 3px 0 3px 20px;">
                                            <select name="ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphContent$gvBasketitem$ctl02$ddlPrint" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_ddlPrint">
                <option selected="selected" value="">--</option>
                <option value="9cmx13cm">9cmx13cm</option>
                <option value="10cmx15cm">10cmx15cm</option>
            </select>
                                        </div>

        </div>
                                </td>
    </tr><tr>
```

I eventually found a solution thanks to the answer below..
This is what I used

```
    var newstr = "1";
var addressValue = "1";
 $(".button.button-dl").click(function () {
      var addressValue = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log("tweede ",addressValue );
      var re = /'(.*?)'/;
      var re2 = /\$/gi;
    var m = addressValue.match(re);

if (m != null)
    idVal = (m[0].replace(re, '$1'));
    console.log("idVal ",idVal);
     var newstr = idVal.replace(/\$/gi, "_").slice(0,-6)+"_hfAsset";    
    console.log("newstr ",newstr);
    console.log(document.getElementById(newstr).value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a hierarchy problem:

First, a CSS problem: `"a.button button-dl"` should be `"a.button.button-dl"` (both classes are on the anchor tag).

Second, that anchor tag is not contained within an `h2`, so your event is never triggering. At best, you can use the `td` tag.

So your JS might look like:

```
$("td").on("click", "a.button.button-dl", function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I added a console.log (" Does it work "); line but when I click a button it doesn't throw a Alert neither do I get a value in the console. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: @GuyForssman Updated my answer with a second issue in your code.

Comment: Hi thank you, Indeed the download button now generates a Alert with text "Download".
This surely helps me in the wright direction.
What I realy need to capture and put into a new value is ""276173"  it's in  <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphContent$gvBasketitem$ctl02$hfAsset" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_gvBasketitem_ctl02_hfAsset" value="276173" />
My problem is in the fact that id and name get their names dynamically

Comment: '$("table").on("click", function () {
  console.log(
     $("[type='hidden']", this).val()
   );
});'
Seems to register the click on Download and results in a Value but it's always the same value